# Connecting to SQL Server in .NET/IKVM using JDBC

Tags: java, .net, sql, jdbc, ikvm

I wrote a Java package which connects to a SQL Server database using JDBC and integrated security. This package runs just as intended from my Java IDE. Now I'm trying to access some classes in this package from a separate .NET app using IKVM.

However, now I'm getting an ExceptionInInitializerError in the .NET app, and the stack trace shows that this error occurs during the database connection initialization.

I created an app.config file for the .NET app to add the JDBC driver to the Java library path using:

```
<add key="ikvm:java.library.path" value="C:\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x64"/>
```

I tried altering the \x64 to \x86 (using the 32-bit auth dll rather than the 64-bit), and I received the exact same error, which I thought was odd. Then I removed this line from the app.config and received a "Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll" warning with a "This driver is not configured for integrated authentication." SQLServerException.

I migrated the database connection code over into VB.NET/IKVM and recreated the original error using these four lines:

```
Dim connectionUrl As String = "jdbc:sqlserver://db\instance;integratedsecurity=true"
Dim driver As String = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"     
java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(New com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver())
Dim dbConn As java.sql.Connection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl)
```

So, I'm pretty sure that, if I can get these four lines working, my problem should be solved. Anybody have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which error and stacktrace occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to track down what's going on is to print the exception (to the console) using the Java Throwable.printStackTrace() method. That way you get the underlying cause.

```
Try
   ...
Catch x as java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
   x.printStackTrace()
End Try
```

My guess is that tThis will show that the problem is that you forgot to copy ikvm-native-win32-x86.dll (or ikvm-native-win32-x64.dll) to your application directory.